# How could design this UI in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

This is the "prototype":

[image]

B1 to B5 are buttons that need to be adjoining and the user has to scroll horizontally.
UP and DOWN are buttons that should be always present on the screen.

I was thinking to use as external layer a classic linear layout but how do I keep UP and DOWN always there centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there have to be a static background for the whole wide panel - it is like panorama metro style application. Once I've done something similar, when I needed buttons on semi transparent layout, and beneath them using RelativeLayout there was a view animator. You could do something similar:

The main Layout will be for example `RelativeLayout`, it will have 3 childs. First is a `HorizontalScrollView`, the second and the third are the buttons on top of the `HorizontalScrollView`, aligned to the top and bottom of the screen. The `HorizontalScrollView` can contain anything - for example a long `LinearLayout`. I think it is possible this way...

Here is a pseudo-layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button/>

    <Button/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where `HorizonralScrollView` will fill the parent relative layout, the first `Button` will be aligned to the top and will be placed over the scroll view, and the second `Button` the same, but aligned to the bottom of the `RelativeLayout` Both can use centerHorizontal and some padding to exact placing.

Comment: I've made another edit, because there is no need to use the framelayouts

Comment: See, shouldn'it be Button - Horizontal - Button instead of Horizontal - Button - Button ?

Comment: No no, because the order in RelativeLayout says, how the z-order will be. In your version, the first button would be hidden by HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Ok, it's working. I actually used android:layout_below to position those. The only "problem" is that now they are all together. I would like to have UP on top of the screen, DOWN on the bottom of the screen and B1 to B5 at the center.